# Dynamic array of dynamic objects

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

Is there any difference between the follow two declarations:

```
Foo* arr = new Foo[10];
```

and

```
Foo** arr = new Foo*[10];
```

in terms of memory allocation?

Comment: yes, the second one has more stars :)

Comment: Yes, there is a big difference between these two declarations.

Comment: Is there any difference between `Foo obj;` and `Foo *obj;`?

Comment: I know what the difference between the two is. I was asking what is the difference in memory allocation between the two declarations, no point being "funny".

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

The first allocates an array of 10 actual  `Foo` objects.

The second allocates an array of 10 pointers to `Foo` objects, but does not allocate the actual objects.

There is a big difference between a `Foo`, and a pointer to a `Foo`.

Comment: I guess Remy Lebeau is a fan of complete answers, instead of just giving the asker the information they need to figure it out themselves.